# Mysql result table joining multiple SELECT results inside a while loop

Tags: mysql

has anyone have an idea of ​​the most efficient way to turn this into a while loop in Mysql?.

```
select * from 1eg_usuarios where 
        user_id_1eg= (select @ult_anf:= id_anfitrion_1eg from 1eg_usuarios where user_id_1eg=121) #40
        or
        user_id_1eg= (select @ult_anf:= id_anfitrion_1eg from 1eg_usuarios where user_id_1eg=@ult_anf) #13
        or
        user_id_1eg= (select @ult_anf:= id_anfitrion_1eg from 1eg_usuarios where user_id_1eg=@ult_anf) #4
        or
        user_id_1eg= (select @ult_anf:= id_anfitrion_1eg from 1eg_usuarios where user_id_1eg=@ult_anf); #1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to query `id_anfitron_1eg` recursively?

MySQL 8.0 introduced the `with` clause

```
 with recursive cte (user_id_1eg, name, id_anfitrion_leg) as (
  select     user_id_1eg, name, id_anfitrion_leg
  from       1eg_usarios
  where      id_anfitrion_leg = 121
  union all
  select     p.user_id_1eg, p.name, p.id_anfitrion_leg

  from       1eg_usarios p
  inner join cte
          on p.id_anfitron_1eg = cte.user_id_1eg
)
select * from cte;
```

[How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)